# Any FACEBOX altenatives?

Tags: facebox

I'm using facebox ( https://github.com/defunkt/facebox ) for calling web pages in modal window.

Is there any RECOMMENDED alternatives to do this?

I prefer jQuery releated solutions.

Regards,
Nuri Akman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I find [jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/), specifically [overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) being very customatizable.

There are a lot of plugins, but it depends on your needs.